# flask-sqlalchemy: how to manipulate properties carried on join tables?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I use flask-sqlalchemy 2.

I have two tables joined by a many to many relationship. This relationship carries a ordinality property because I want it to eventually be edited in the future.

```
visualisations = db.Table(
    "visualisations",
    db.Column("page_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("page.id"), primary_key=True),
    db.Column(
        "visualisation_id",
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("visualisation.id"),
        primary_key=True,
    ),
    db.Column("ordinalite", db.Integer, nullable=False),
)


@dataclass
class Page(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "page"
    id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    localisation: str = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)

    visualisations = db.relationship(
        "Visualisation",
        secondary=visualisations,
        lazy="subquery",
        backref=db.backref("pages", lazy=True),
    )


@dataclass
class Visualisation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "visualisation"

    id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    graphe_id: str = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
```

For now, I'm able to insert a new page with this code:

```
v1 = Visualisation(graphe_id = "graphe_id_1")
v2 = Visualisation(graphe_id = "graphe_id_2")

page = Page()
page.localisation = "localisation"
page.visualisations = [v1, v2]

db.session.add(page)
db.session.commit()
```

By doing this, cardinality property is set to 0 for each relationship.
I want to be able to manually set the ordinality property.

Here is some pseudocode:

```py
v1 = Visualisation(graphe_id = "graphe_id_1")
v2 = Visualisation(graphe_id = "graphe_id_2")

page = Page()
page.localisation = "localisation"

# pseudocode
page.visualisations = [
  { "value": v1, "ordinalite": 1 },
  { "value": v2, "ordinalite": 2 },
]
#

db.session.add(page)
db.session.commit()
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: I just edited the question in that direction. I would want to be able to manually set the ordinalite property of the join.

Comment: You probably want the [association proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) feature.